# Magento skin url 'default' replaced with 'theme'?

Tags: php, css, magento, url-rewriting, theming

I am using a custom theme on magento and in my header.phtml, used the following code:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('').'images/logo_white.gif'//$this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
    </a>
</div>
```

When I first load the homepage, the getSkinUrl gives me this path:

http://site.address.com/skin/frontend/THEME/DEFAULT/images/logo_white.gif

However, when I load any other page, I get:

http://site.address.com/skin/frontend/THEME/THEME/images/logo_white.gif

I couldn't find why the skin path would change if it wasn't a homepage anywhere. The only different is we have this one effect that layers a logo on top of the base one to change color:

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
<div class="back-header">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
```

But that was working before?

Let me know what you guys think. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set the URL in the Administration `System(Menu) -> Configuration -> General(Sidebar) -> Design -> Header(Section) -> Logo Image Src`. And make sure your theme defines this or Magento fallbacks will occur where your definition doesn't exist. Then revert the hardcoded link back to `$this->getLogoSrc()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answers you question, but it may solve your problem.
You should never use `getSkinUrl()` with an empty parameter.
So instead of this:

```
echo $this->getSkinUrl('').'images/logo_white.gif'
```

use

```
echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/logo_white.gif');
```

Magento looks for the specified path in the current theme. If it finds it, it returns the url to the resource. If not, it looks in the theme you set as default, and if it's not there either it will return the url for that resource from `base/default` ignoring if the resource is there or not.

**[EDIT]**.
I may have an idea also why you get different values for different pages.
In `header.phtml` there should be 2 sections of code for the logo. One for the homepage and one for the rest of the pages. Maybe you modified only one.

```
<?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?> <-- for homepage-->
    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
<?php else:?><-- for the rest of the pages-->
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
<?php endif?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had used an empty getSkinUrl() before and no "else" specified as well, and it had worked. Very odd.

Comment: Maybe you were just lucky. :) Anyway, you shouldn't use the method with an empty parameter.